# What offices/divisions of U.S. federal agencies and bureaus can do site inspections at private companies?

Tags: usa, government

Hoping that someone somewhere collated this stuff already - is there any single dataset that lists all federal offices that can do compliance on-site inspections of any kind? The Federal Register is huge, and life is short.